# RegEx for matching uppercase and dash followed by a comma

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

Trying to remove strings that follow the pattern

Tag Starts With

```
Size:
```

and before the next COMMA (,) includes the `-` character.

Example:

```
Size: XS-S-M-L-XL-2XL,
```

or

```
Size: XS-S-M,
```

etc.

WOULD get selected (including `,`)

but `Size_S,` would be ignored because there is no `-`

I'm close with:

```
Size:(.*)-*(.?),
```

But still not stopping at `,`

Here is 1 line of tags:

```
Athletics, Fitted, Mesh, Feature_Moisture Wicking, Material_Polyester 100%, , Material_Polyester 100%, Material_Polyester Over 50%,  School, Style_Short Sleeves, Size_2XL, Size_L, Size_M, Size_S, Size_XL, Size_XS, Size: XS-S-M-L-XL-2XL, Uniforms, Unisex, V-Neck, VisibleLogos, Youth
```

To remove all size 'range' tags from my cells and only leave the single size tag.

**Solution can be found here:  regex101.com/r/VuTzba/1**

Comment: How about using [negated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) comma [like this](https://regex101.com/r/K4qgib/1) instead of the dot.

Comment: What would the tag look like if the product only came in Small? Would it look like `Size: S` with no dash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern `Size:(.*)-*(.?),` you are first matching until the end of the string using `(.*)`.

After that the hyphen `-*` and single character in the group `(.?)` are optional so it will backtrack until the last comma as that is the only character that has to be matched.

To get a more exact match, you could use a repeating pattern to match the sizes:

```
Size: (?:\d*X[SL]|L|M|S)(?:-(?:\d*X[LS]|L|M|S))*,
```

**Explanation**

- `Size:` Match Size followed by a space
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d*X[SL]|L|M|S` match one of the listed items in the alternation
- `)` Close group
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `-(?:\d*X[LS]|L|M|S)` Match a hyphen followed by any of the listed items
- `)*,` Close group and repeat 0+ times and match a comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fQwTxO/1)

As more broader pattern could be using a character class and list all the allowed characters `Size: [XSML\d]+(?:-[XSML\d]+)*,` or match until the first comma `Size:[^,]+,`

**Edit**

To also match `Size: 28W-30W-32W-34W-36W-38W-40W, Size: 28W-30W-32W-34W` or  you could use extend the character class adding `|\d+W` to it and end the pattern matching either a comma or assert the end of the string `$`

```
Size: (?:\d*X[SL]|L|M|S|\d+W)(?:-(?:\d*X[LS]|L|M|S|\d+W))*(?:,|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PXBm7M/1)

Comment: You saved me a TON of time! So awesome, thank you very much!

Comment: Only issue is that this doesn't pickup 
tags Like 
`Size: 28W-30W-32W-34W-36W-38W-40W,
Size: 28W-30W-32W-34W`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Sure, you could add that optiion to the alternation https://regex101.com/r/fQwTxO/2  and perhaps make the comma at the end optional `,?`

Comment: Again, I'm real thankful for your help and the first suggestion you gave DID help clear out most of the clutter, but I'm still having a bit of trouble removing the other sizes like I mentioned above. 

The revision you made did pickup most of the problem sizes but it also picks up tags that don't have the `-` character. For example `Size: 34W,` is being captured also when it shouldn't be. 

I've updated https://regex101.com/r/fQwTxO/3 
With some more tags to give you a better look, if you have the time to check it out. 

Thank  you!

Comment: This did help remove a bit more, but just to show you the mess I am still left with, I've shared the remaining parsed lines. 
https://regex101.com/r/fQwTxO/5
Normally, everyone of these lines would end with `,` but I replace with `/n` to view easier.

Comment: @WillRodgers Perhaps this will get all your matches https://regex101.com/r/VuTzba/1

Answer (score 0):

We might want to add more boundaries in our expression here. Let's start with something similar to:

```
Size:\s+([A-Z0-9-]+),
```

where the capturing group `()` collects our desired data.

[image]

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kGqG4l/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) also helps to visualize the expressions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Size:\s*(.*?),` will grab everything after the colon and before the next comma skipping leading white space.